# mshtml.IHTMLDocument returning nothing

Tags: vb.net

I have the below code trying to access a webpage and the program is erroring out at a test for the innerHTML property. Below is the code:

```
 iex = GetObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")
 iex.visible = True
 iex.navigate("https://url.aspx")

 While iex.readystate <> 4 Or iex.busy
      Application.DoEvents()
 End While

 Dim htdoc As mshtml.IHTMLDocument = iex.Document
 Dim htstring As mshtml.IHTMLBodyElement = htdoc.body
 If (InStr(htstring.innerHTML, "An error occured while processing your request") > 0) Then
```

The last line is where it gets the error. And I have determined that it gets the error because htdoc is nothing, resulting in everything else being nothing. At least, that is what I believe the issue to be.

After further troubleshooting, the below line is what is causing the error.

```
 mshtml.IHTMLBodyElement = htdoc.body
```

The exception error is:

> Message = Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A01B6
>
> Item = In order to evaluate an indexed
>   property, the property must be qualified and the arguments must be
>   explicitly supplied by the user.

This was working before IE was updated to IE11 (I don't recall what version it was prior, but I would assume it was IE10).

I don't think I am doing anything wrong, but any help you could provide would be greatly beneficial!

Comment: Fairly misleading info, only the HRESULT looks accurate.  Try `htstring As mshtml.IHTMLElement` instead.

Comment: I received the same error message after trying that change. I suppose I don't understand what's occurring, but I am very confident that the issue is with the htdoc.

Comment: After further troubleshooting, it does appear that the 'htstring As mshtml.IHTMLBodyElement = htdoc.body' is the line that is causing the error. However, changing htstring to IHTMLElement still causes the error. I've updated the initial question.